# What is the other parameter returned by DataLoader.dataset.samples[i]

Tags: python, torch

I'm using the `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` to lookup the filename in an iterable-style dataset. When calling `DataLoader.dataset.samples[i]` within an the iterative loop, I get the filename and an integer.
Example:

```
('car.JPEG', 0)
```

What does the second parameter stand for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataLoader` returns each member of the `dataset` object which is a tuple containing the sample and the class_index it belongs to. So in your case, the first index of the tuple contains the sample (`car.JEPG`) and the second index is the class_index that the sample belongs to (`0` in your case). To learn more go through the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html).